# Pass powershell exception to html body for sending mail

Tags: html, powershell

I have written a powershell script which will check website's 200 status. If it fails to find status 200, then powershell throws exception message and will mail for notification with html body. But i can not pass the throw exception message to html body, it shows direct variable name on html page. Is it possible to pass the varible value to html body?

Here is the script,

```
try {
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://google.com/')
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
        Write-Host "Site is OK!"
    } 
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Website not Okay"
    $string_err = $_ | Out-String
    Write-Host $string_err
    $body = @'
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Error: $string_err</p>

    </body>
    </html>
'@
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xxxxx@gmail.com", $secpasswd)
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Credential $cred -UseSsl -From 'xxxxx@gmail.com' -To 'yyyyyy@gmail.com' -Subject 'Website status Error' -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
    Continue
}
```

Comment: Use a double-quoted here-string `$body = @" ... "@`. Because of the single-quotes, the variable `$string_err` will not be expanded, but taken as literal text instead. As aside, your code could do with better indentation..

Comment: As a side note, the script will not throw an exception if status code differs from 200 but just fails silently. Also, exceptions are not a branching construct, so consider the design a bit more.